# How to get flags returned by recvmsg() with recvfrom()

Tags: linux, sockets

I have to use `recvfrom()` to receive from multiple interfaces (unknown at compile-time, and also needed for preserving the exact order of messages as opposed to using individual syscalls to receive from each interface in turn), but I also need access to some flags that only `recvmsg()` provides (via the `flags` field of the message header that is modified by the call).

Is there a way to use `recvfrom()` to fill a `msgheader` similar to `recvmsg()`?

Comment: Isn't `recvmsg()` a functional superset of `recvfrom()`? I'm pretty sure that if you use `recvmsg()` you will get the sender address in the `struct msghdr` structure.

Comment: You're right; care to submit it as answer if you need the points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`recvmsg()` is a functional superset of `recvfrom()`, just as `recvfrom()` is a functional superset of `recv()`. In other words, `recvmsg()` is the most powerful of the three functions, and everything that you can do with the other two you can also do with `recvmsg()`.

In particular, `recvfrom()`'s main feature is that it returns the address of the sender of the message that is received. The same information is available when you use `recvmsg()`: look at the `msg_name` and `msg_namelen` elements of the `struct msghdr`.